# Get a list of pushed files from a python script, while GitHub Action on push

Tags: git, github-actions, python-3.11

I'm trying to get the list of last commit pushed files whereas a pushed commit is triggering a GitHub Action. The most difficult, is that I need to get this files from a `subprocess.getoutput()` method of/in Python. Here is my problematic command.

```
git_diff = subprocess.getoutput('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $GITHUB_SHA')
```

The Ubuntu server on GitHubActions is correctly installed and every needed libraries are setup, but when I use a debug code to `print('git_diff :' + git_diff)`, it returns, as a result:

```
git_diff: fatal: ambiguous argument 'zag2b54s': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

While it works perfectly locally, my git command doesn't work on GitHub Actions, perhaps it depends of my mastering of Git, or maybe it is a problem with GitHub Actions. I really don't know.

Does someone know which git command to enter, in order to get the list of the last commit pushed files, from a Python script, on a GitHub Actions server?

I tried many times the code locally, and it works very well, but some strange things made commit hash unknown.
Maybe it is a problem of read/write inside yml github action file.
I don't exactly know where to search.

Please found attached some relevant parts of my yaml workflow file :

```yaml
name: Automation for csv, py and diagrams files of Sequel pushed files

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions: write-all

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.11
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.11"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        sudo apt-get update -y \
            && sudo apt-get upgrade -y \
            && sudo apt-get install graphviz git -y \
            && python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
            && pip install pandas sql-metadata diagrams
    - name: App with Automation for csv and diagrams
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        python automation_csv_diagram.py --last_commit
```

Then, the same thing for my python script (it works either locally or on GitHub Actions) :

```py
import subprocess
import sys
from glob import glob
from re import findall, IGNORECASE, match, MULTILINE, search, S, sub

global REQUEST_DIR
REQUEST_DIR = "bq"


def pickup(lastcommit_fct: bool) -> List[str]:
    """
    :param lastcommit_fct: bool
    Récupère la liste des fichiers sql dans les sous répertoires
    :return: List[str]
    """
    global REQUEST_DIR
    if lastcommit_fct:
        if not os.name == "nt":  # Test que le système utilisé n'est pas Windows mais ubuntu dans GitHub Actions
            git_diff = subprocess.getoutput('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $GITHUB_SHA')
        else:
            git_diff = subprocess.getoutput('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD')
        files = findall("(.*\.sql)", git_diff, MULTILINE | IGNORECASE)
##DEBUG MODE###############################
        mode = True
        if mode:
            var_githubsha = subprocess.getoutput("echo $GITHUB_SHA")
            sys.exit('github sha: ' + var_githubsha + "\ngit_diff: " + git_diff + '\nfiles: ' + str(files))
###########################################
        if len(files) > 0:
            files = [y for y in [x.strip() for x in files] if match(r".*\.sql", y, IGNORECASE)]
        else:
            sys.exit("Pas de fichier SQL dans le dernier commit git_diff" + git_diff)

    if not lastcommit_fct:
        files: list = glob(f'{REQUEST_DIR}/**/*.sql')
    return sorted(files)


def main(lastcommit_fct):
    files = pickup(lastcommit_fct)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    option = str(sys.argv[1])
    if option == "--all_directories":
        main(False)  # Pour générer tous les documents SQL du répertoire ./bq
    elif option == "--last_commit":
        main(True)  # Pour ne générer que les documents SQL du dernier commit
    else:
        print("""Lancer le script pour tous les fichiers Sequel du répertoire ./bq:
$python automation_csv_diagram --all_directories

Lancer le script pour tous les derniers fichiers Sequel venant d'être poussés
$python automation_csv_diagram --last_commit""")
```

Sorry for not-French speakers, all commentaries are not in English.

Comment: Are you running this as part of a script or directly from command line? Example of command line: `python3 -c "import subprocess; print(subprocess.getoutput('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $GITHUB_SHA'))"`

Comment: I'm running this as a part of a python script, that I launch from a github actions yaml file as this ```python script.py --last_commit```

Comment: Please add this to your question with the relevant parts of your workflow as well.

Comment: I believe you need `os.environ['GITHUB_SHA']` in the script. Here's an example: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/blob/423a54765cf304865a72111410fbcb8afbec8b81/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L33-L44. Sample run: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/3902840388/jobs/6666391469

Comment: Apart from that, when you said it worked locally, how did you test it? Could you please add that too? I mean testing with `GITHUB_SHA` locally. Or, was it with `HEAD` only?

Comment: Of course, this present the fact that, my problem was the escape of the variable $GITHUB_SHA inside the method subprocess.getoutput(), still with your nice peace of code, GitHub Actions return again (same problem, same issue !) :  
github sha: 91764ab08f865d087b7c8e86eaa0c23b6958i89c
git_diff: 
files: [] At the end, locally, I'm using HEAD instead of GITHUB_SHA.

Comment: That means your problem as mentioned is the question is now resolved. The value of `GITHUB_SHA` i.e. `91764ab08f865d087b7c8e86eaa0c23b6958i89c` is now printing and being used in `subprocess.getoutput()` successfully. The above message is coming from the next lines. With `mode = True`, it'll always exit with that message. Also, you need to verify whether you changed any `.sql` files in your last commit that should show up next.

Comment: The message from your question i.e. `git_diff: fatal: ambiguous argument 'zag2b54s': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` and this next one i.e. `github sha: 91764ab08f865d087b7c8e86eaa0c23b6958i89c git_diff: files: []` are not the same. The first one was coming from `subprocess.getoutput()` and the second one is from `sys.exit()`.

Comment: I've found that page https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-git-changed-files to make my believes splashed on the ground. It requires a kind modification of my Python script and one on my Yaml File but it does work. Thank you all !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP found a different method to solve this problem which renders this question invalid now.